# Equivalent definitions of semicontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, semicontinuous-functions

I am trying to understand the equivalence between two definitions of an upper semicontinuous real-valued function over a compact normed space $X$.

Suppose that for every $y$ in some set $Y$, the function $f(x,y): X\times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ is upper semicontinuous in $x$ over $X$.

Using the usually used definition this means

> for every fixed $y \in Y$ and every sequence $\{x_k\}$ in $X$ such
>   that $x_k \to x$, the following inequality holds
>    \begin{equation}
> \underset{k\to \infty}{\lim\sup} f(x_k,y) \leq f(x,y) 
> \end{equation}

The question is how to show that this definition is equivalent to the following:

> for every fixed $y \in Y$, all $x \in X$, and some $\epsilon >0$  the following convergence holds
>    \begin{equation}
> \sup_{\|\tilde{x} - x  \|<\epsilon} f(\tilde{x},y) \to f(x,y) \;\;\; \text{ as } \;\;\; \epsilon \to 0
> \end{equation}
>   where $\|\cdot\|$ is some norm defined over $X$.

I have read a formal topological definition on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity#Formal_definition) that seems close to the second definition above. In the topological definition, one fix $\epsilon$ first and then the neighborhood exists such that the equality shown there holds. It seems that the second definition above requires the reverse; i.e. as we let $\epsilon$ go to zero, the neighborhood becomes a singleton and the inequality becomes an equality.

Any clarification or a citation to a reference where this is clarified ia appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the second definition holds. Take a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of points of $X$ convergeng to $x$. Now, take $\varepsilon'>0$. Then there is a $\varepsilon>0$ such that$$\left\lvert\sup_{\lVert\tilde x-x\rVert<\varepsilon}f(\tilde x,y)-f(x,y)\right\rvert<\varepsilon'.$$Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$, you have $\lVert x_n-x\rVert<\varepsilon$ if $n\gg1$. But then$$f(x_n,y)-f(x,y)\leqslant\sup_{\lVert\tilde x-x\rVert<\varepsilon}f(\tilde x,y)-f(x,y)<\varepsilon'.$$Since this inequality occurs when $n$ is large enough, $\limsup_{n\to\infty}f(x_n,y)-f(x,y)\leqslant\varepsilon'$. And since *this* inequality occurs for every $\varepsilon'>0$, $\limsup_{n\to\infty}f(x_n,y)\leqslant f(x,y)$.

This proves that if $f$ is uppor semicontinuous according to the second definition, that it is also upper semicontinuous with respect to the first one.

Can you prove now that the reverse implication also holds?

Comment: One comment: I think you mean "... since $f$ is upper semicontinuous...". (I have not worked out the other direction yet)

Comment: I've edited my answer. Thank you.